# PhoneGap.exec to Cordova.exec

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using a plugin in my Cordova project and it's installed properly, but doesn't work. Upon looking into the JS file I found these two lines

```
PhoneGap.exec("SMSComposer.showSMSComposer",args);
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
```

Obviously the problem is that the PhoneGap.exec function no longer exists, it's Cordova.exec now. How can I get this working? The plugin isn't that old, just a few months so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

can u give the cordova version you are using ?, if you are using new phonegap version , use plugin for that version. If it is  your custom plugin please follow this 
[Plugin dev guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) . Or check this [Upgrading Guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides).

- cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "service",
           "action", ["firstArgument", "secondArgument", 42,
           false]);
  The parameters explained in more detail:

function(winParam) {} - Success function callback. Assuming your exec call completes successfully, this function will be invoked (optionally with any parameters you pass back to it)
function(error) {} - Error function callback. If the operation does not complete successfully, this function will be invoked (optionally with an error parameter)
"service" - The service name to call into on the native side. This will be mapped to a native class. More on this in the native guides below
"action" - The action name to call into. This is picked up by the native class receiving the exec call, and, depending on the platform, essentially maps to a class's method. For more detail please check out the native guides located at the end of this article.
[/* arguments */] - Arguments to get passed into the native environment

links to latest SMS composer Plugin : IOS [Link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/SMSComposer),
Android :[link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPluginForCordovaVersion3.2)

i think it may help you